# Almost conjugate subgroups of compact simple Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes, isospectrality

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group.

**Definition:**
Two finite subgroups $H_1,H_2$ of $G$ are said to be *almost conjugate* in $G$ if $|H_1\cap [g]_G| = |H_2\cap [g]_G|$ for all $g\in G$, where $[g]_G=\{hgh^{-1}: h\in G\}$ is the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$.

This is equivalent to

- the left regular representations $L^2(G/H_1)$ and $L^2(G/H_2)$ are equivalent (as $G$-modules).
- there is a bijection $\varphi:H_1\to H_2$ such that $h$ and $\varphi(h)$ are conjugate in $G$ for all $h\in H_1$.

> **General question:** Which simply-connected compact simple Lie groups admits almost conjugate but
> not conjugate finite subgroups?

Here is what I know so far.
From a classical example by Gassmann, we have the following almost conjugate (but not conjugate) subgroups of $\SO(6)$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H_1 &=
\left\{
{I}_{6},
\; 
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0 \\
&&0&1\\
&&1&0\\
&&&& 1\\
&&&&& 1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&&1&\\
&0&&1 \\
1&&0&\\
&1&&0\\
&&&& 1\\
&&&&& 1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&&&1\\
&0&1 \\
&1&0\\
1&&&0\\
&&&& 1\\
&&&&& 1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\right\},
\\
%
%
%
H_2 &=
\left\{
{I}_{6},
\;
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0 \\
&&0&1\\
&&1&0\\
&&&&1 \\
&&&&&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0 \\
&&1&&&\\
&&&1&&\\
&&&&0&1\\
&&&&1&0 
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
1&&&\\
&1& \\
&&0&1&\\
&&1&0\\
&&&&0&1&\\
&&&&1&0
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\right\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Their preimages $\widetilde H_1,\widetilde H_2$ of the $2$-cover $\textrm{Spin}(6)\to \SO(6)$ are almost conjugate (but not conjugate) in $\textrm{Spin}(6)\simeq \SU(4)$.
Moreover, $\widetilde H_1,\widetilde H_2$ are almost conjugate and non-conjugate subgroups of

- $\SU(n)$ for any $n\geq4$ via the standard embedding $\SU(4)\hookrightarrow \SU(n)$,
- $\textrm{Spin}(n)$ for $n\geq 6$ via $\textrm{Spin}(6)\hookrightarrow \textrm{Spin}(n)$,
- $\Sp(n)$ for $n\geq4$ via $\SU(4)\hookrightarrow U(4)\hookrightarrow \Sp(n)$,
- ${E}_n$ for $n=6,7,8$ via $\SO(6)\hookrightarrow \SO(10)\hookrightarrow {E}_6\hookrightarrow {E}_7\hookrightarrow {E}_8$, and
- ${F}_4$ via $\textrm{Spin}(4) \hookrightarrow \textrm{Spin}(9)\hookrightarrow {F}_4$.

I hope this reasoning is correct.

One can easily see from the classification of finite subgroups (up to conjugation) of $\SU(2)$ that almost conjugate subgroups of $\SU(2)$ are necessarily conjugate.

The only remaining simply-connected compact simple Lie groups are $\SU(3)$, $\Sp(2)\simeq \textrm{Spin}(5)$, $\Sp(3)$, and $G_2$.

> **Main question:** Are there almost conjugate and non-conjugate finite
> subgroups of $\SU(3)$ (resp. $\Sp(2)$, $\Sp(3)$, and $G_2$)?

The interest on this group theoretical question is its application to inverse spectral geometry. Namely, the manifold $G/H_1$ and $G/H_1$ endowed with the restriction of a bi-invariant metric on $G$ are isospectral, that is, their Laplace-Beltrami operators have the same spectra.